# Difference between "particularly" and "in particular"

Tags: difference, synonyms

There are 2 sentences :

> 1. I particularly like the blue shirt.
> 2. In particular, I like the blue shirt.

As far as I understand they have different meanings. But there is one more example:

> 3. I like the blue shirt in particular.

Which of the first two sentences is the third one similar in meaning to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence (3) means the same as sentence (2) - that the speaker is singling out the blue shirt as a garment they especially like.

Comment: All three sentences are saying that the blue shirt is being singled out over other shirts. They are all correct.